# How to create distributed load testing using vegeta with golang?

Tags: go, load-testing, distributed, vegeta

I need to distribute the load across multiple client machines(Distributed attacks). I need to do it from the attacker in the go lang script not from pdsh for orchestration.
Below is my vegeta script.

attacker := vegeta.NewAttacker(vegeta.Timeout(1600*time.Second), vegeta.Connections(10000000), )
ramp1 := attacker.Attack(targeter, rampUpRate1, rampUpDuration1, "Ramp-1 !!") {

Comment: There's a thread on GitHub of vegeta where people share thier Kubernetes-based solutions for distrubuted load testing: https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/issues/336.